# Alternative to WinForms for Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, winforms

I have developed a program that I want to install on an Android device. However, since this is my first time with this I was not properly prepared, and I have learned that both .NET is no compatible with the Android OS, and WinForms are not compatible with Android compilers.

I have done some research, and found [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform) and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) to be my closest bets, however the issue still remains that I am unable to find a way to get this program onto my tablet.

Is there another alternative to WinForms that I can easily adapt my already built program, to compile and use with Android?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to convert a .NET windows forms project to a Java Android project.

Sharing business logic can be done using Xamarin (C#) if you've build your initial project with a good architecture (Seperation of business logic from the UI). Then you can move your business logic project (Or Classes) to a PCL (Portable class library) inside your new Xamarin Forms project. And all you whould have to do is create the equivalent UI and attach it to your business logic. Note that due to cross platform restrictions, not all the API's used in windows forms might be available for use by the PCL.

However for the UI, There is no possible way. This is even worse that the questions asking to convert windows forms project to WPF as both are MS technologies and might have some in common. But for Android XAML layouts and Windows forms design generated by code, there is no tool AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda not possible.

First - Why do you need winforms in Android? The screens are 5.0 - 6.0 inches and it'll be to small and hard to control. And even if you want the forms to be displayed in fullscreen - the performances would be slow!

Second - Windows is one OS and Android is another OS (based on Linux) - which means they have differrent compilers...

Third - If you are good in C#, I recommend Xamarin!

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial post, I was not properly prepared for this, and was unaware of the requirements/restrictions. As others have suggested, WinForms is not compatible/inadvisable to be used with Android (as you have also pointed out), so I am asking for an easy alternative to WinForms that can be used instead.